# Alternative definition for disconnected

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

I define a new concept below, with a question on this concept at the end.

Let $X$ be a topological space. Then, say that $X$ is *discontinuous* if there exists a pair of non-empty partitioning sets $U,V$ such that for any arbitrary topological space $Y$, and any pair of continuous functions $f:U\to Y$, $g:V\to Y$, the function $h:X \to Y$ obtained by "stitching together" $f$ and $g$ is continuous.

**Proposition**: Discontinuous $\iff$ disconnected.

**Proof of forward implication**: Let $Y = \mathbb{Z}$, $f \equiv 1$, $g \equiv 0$. Then $h$ is (by assumption) a continous but non-constant function from $X \to \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $X$ is disconnected.

**Proof of reverse implication**: This follows directly from the gluing lemma.

---

It is notable that in the forward implication, the argument does not show that the partitioning sets $U,V$ disconnect $X$ as (ex-ante) they are not open sets. If $X,Y$ are both metric spaces, then I believe that you can show that $U,V$ must be open i.e. they disconnect $X$.

**Question**: Is the same true for general topological spaces $X,Y$? (Must $U,V$ be open in this case also?)

Intuitively, should I expect this to be a difficult question to answer?

Comment: The reverse implication is just an application of the pasting lemma

Comment: @arnett Yes, it could be considered a special case of the lemma. That's a good way to summarise the proof; I'll edit the question.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: I think the confusion may be the same as the one that I had originally; namely, since the question ("are $U$ and $V$ necessarily open?") is in the middle of the text, and is *not* the bit set off in bold, it's easy to miss at first what you are actually asking.

Comment: @LSpice That's fair. I appreciated when writing that that needing multiple paragraphs of setup for a one-line question was not really ideal. I'll try to reformat the text a bit for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you should intuitively expect the question to be difficult, but you've already answered it:  if you take $f = 1$ on $U$ and $g = 0$ on $V$, and write $h$ for the resulting pasted function on $X$, then $U$ equals $h^{-1}\bigl((0, \infty)\bigr)$ and $V$ equals $h^{-1}\bigl((-\infty, 1)\bigr)$, so both are open.

Comment: You may want to slightly adjust your choice of intervals, but thank you for the answer. I am a little bit embarrassed.

Comment: The intervals look right to me, though maybe I'm just blind to my own typo.  What should they be?

Comment: Nope, I failed to read properly and now am a little bit more embarrassed. Thanks again!